# How to deploy dash app with states using Heroku?

Tags: python, docker, heroku, plotly-dash

So I successfully deployed my dash app with Heroku.
My app has many tabs and saves the state for each tab. Meaning if the user changed the table in one tab and then switch to another tab and comeback to the tab then the table has the same content as before.

The problem is that I don't want the state to be saved if the user exit the site and then entered again.

So far during the development I achieved this by running the python command for running the app again, but now I can't do this (I launched the app with Docker container and it's seems that one image is shared between all the sessions).

Is there a way in Heroku to solve this problem? maybe create a new image for each new sessions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you create an image to release your application (say v1.0) and run it on Docker env (Heroku or other platforms). The application runs in a container and serves all users: every restart or redeploying a new image would need a downtime which impacts everyone.

The solution (for what I can understand) is that you want to clear the session data for a given user, so the saved state wont be used at the next access.
I think you should look at doing that in your app: for example when accessing the home url (ie entrypoint of your app) clear any setting related to the user (which you would typically recognised with a cookie).

Not if it help, if not share more details on how you save the user state.

Comment: I saved my user state in a specific class used for this purpose. The problem with what you are suggesting is inconsistent state when multiple users access the app, what do you think?

Comment: How do you distinguish between different users?

Comment: Right now I don't

Comment: If you have single user then you need to clear the state (reset data in the class) whenever the user access the homepage, so he/she gets a clean state.

Comment: And in case of multiple users that can access the app simultaneously?

Comment: In your class you need a map (or list) to save the state for each user, then you need to recognise the users. Usually you do this with a cookie: set a cooking when a user visits the site so you can see when he/she comes back, assign an ID to the user and store in the class where you save the state.